# "Unsupported Paths Count" when creating item in CosmosDB

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, partition, database-partitioning

I have a Cosmos DB container that contains hierarchical partition keys. The first partition key is **/WaID**, and the second partition key is **/Media**. I am using `container.create_item(message_item)` in an Azure Function to create an item in the container. Below is the structure of `message_item`. Information in `message_item` is obtained from a request sent by Twilio on WhatsApp whenever a message is sent to that Twilio number.

```
message_item = {
            "id": sms_message_sid,
            "WaId": wa_id,
            "Media": "false",
            "NumMedia": num_media,
            "ProfileName": profile_name,
            "SmsStatus": sms_status,
            "Body": body,
            "To": to,
            "NumSegments": num_segments,
            "ReferralNumMedia": referral_num_media,
            "AccountSid": account_sid,
            "From": sender_number,
            "ApiVersion": api_version,   
        }
```

When I send a message to the Twilio WhatsApp number, the request is sent to the Azure Function and information is obtained. However the following error occurs when the line `create_item` is running.
*ps: The error does not occur when I `create_item` in a Cosmos DB container with only one partition key. The error also does not occur if I'm creating the item manually on the Azure Cosmos DB interface, using the exact same values in `message_item` that is passed from Twilio.*

```
ValueError: Unsupported paths count.
```

---

I tried explicitly determining the partition keys like below:

```
partition_key_values = {
    "WaId": wa_id,
    "Media": "false"
}
```

and used `create_item` like this:

```
container.create_item(message_item, partition_key=partition_key_values)
```

but it doesnt work
---

Any idea on how to create_item the right way for containers with hierarchical partition keys?

Comment: what is the SDK you are using

Comment: If this is Python SDK, support for Hierarchical Partition Keys were [just merged](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/pull/31121) and I don't think it was yet released

Comment: I'm using python SDK, thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0):

This feature is now in prerelease for `azure-cosmos 4.5.2b1`. You'll have to install that version or higher (for future readers when it is released). Information on how to use it may be found here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/pull/31121